# Upgrading S3Client to S3AsyncClient how to get Publisher<ByteBuffer>?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, stream, reactor, publisher

I am upgrading S3Client in aws cloud service to S3AsyncClient.

I have this function to convert to async:

```
public PutObjectResponse uploadFileByUrl(String fileUrl, String builderId, PbModel category, String categoryId)

    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    String[] fileNameArray = url.getFile().split("\\.");
    var uniqueFileName = prepareFileName(fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length -1]);

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    long contentSize = connection.getContentLengthLong();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    return s3Client.putObject(myObjectRequestBuild, RequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream, contentSize));
}
```

I have this function to convert to async:

```
public CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> uploadFileByUrl(String fileUrl, String builderId, PbModel category, String categoryId)

    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    String[] fileNameArray = url.getFile().split("\\.");
    var uniqueFileName = prepareFileName(fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length -1]);

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    long contentSize = connection.getContentLengthLong();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    return asyncClient.putObject(myObjectRequestBuild, AsyncRequestBody.fromPublisher(???));
}
```

As you can see in second method above when I convert the first function above to async I need to use AsyncRequestBody instead of RequestBody.
AsyncRequestBody doesn't have fromInputStream method but it have fromPublisher method that I want to use, the fromPublisher method get as parameter type of Publisher.

So my question is how to convert my inputStream into an Publisher?

Comment: Consider to use `fromFile()` instead: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromFile-java.io.File-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> AsyncRequestBody doesn't have `fromInputStream` method

Correct however, it has a plethora of other ways to create an `AsyncRequestBody`:

1. [`fromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromByteBuffer-java.nio.ByteBuffer-)
2. [`fromBytes(byte[] bytes)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromBytes-byte:A-)
3. [`fromFile(File file)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromFile-java.io.File-)
4. [`fromFile(Path path)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromFile-java.nio.file.Path-)
5. [`fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<ByteBuffer> publisher)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromPublisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)
6. [`fromString(String string)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromString-java.lang.String-)
7. [`fromString(String string, Charset cs)`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncRequestBody.html#fromString-java.lang.String-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Considering the above, you have a few solutions:

1. Convert the `InputStream` to a byte array using `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` (or in Java 9+, [`inputStream.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--)) and then use `fromBytes` directly
2. As above but then convert the `byte[]` to a `ByteBuffer` using `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)` and then use `fromByteBuffer`
3. Create a new [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object specifying a filename, copy the contents of the `InputStream` to the file's `FileOutputStream` using [`IOUtils.copy()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), and then use `fromFile(File file)`
4. As above but instead of providing the `File` object, provide its path to `fromFile(Path path)` after you've written to it's `FileOutputStream`
5. Convert the `InputSteam` to a `Publisher<ByteArray>` using [`DataBufferUtils.readByteChannel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE_to_5.0.3.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%205.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html) from the Spring Framework, Akka [`StreamConverters`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/StreamConverters$.html#fromInputStream(in:()=%3Ejava.io.InputStream,chunkSize:Int):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source%5Bakka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future%5Bakka.stream.IOResult%5D%5D) etc. and then use `fromPublisher`
6. Convert the `InputStream` to a UTF-8 encoded `String` then use `fromString(String string)` (no need to specify the `Charset` if it is UTF-8 encoded)
7. Convert the `InputStream` to a non-UTF-8 encoded `String` then use `fromString(String string, Charset cs)`, specifying the `CharSet`

Of course, some of the above are plain redundant in your case e.g. `fromFile(Path path)` is for files that you've already stored & converting the `InputSteam` to a `Publisher<ByteArray>` is going to be a pain but I've included all possible solutions for completeness.

---

I would approach this using solution #1, resulting in the cleanest, simplest code out of the above.

**Convert the `InputStream` to `byte[]` using `inputStream.readAllBytes()` and then use `AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes(...)`**.

This should work:

```
public CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> uploadFileByUrl(String fileUrl, String builderId, PbModel category, String categoryId)
    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    String[] fileNameArray = url.getFile().split("\\.");
    var uniqueFileName = prepareFileName(fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length -1]);

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    long contentSize = connection.getContentLengthLong();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    byte[] fileByteArray = inputStream.readAllBytes();

    return asyncClient.putObject(myObjectRequestBuild, AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes(fileByteArray));
}
```